# Android OnTouchListener results in jerky drags

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a button (variable theButton in code), and want to be able to drag it around its parent view.
Here is its OnTouchListener:

```
    OnTouchListener touchBListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {       
        public float offsetX;
        public float offsetY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            int theAction = event.getAction();
            switch (theAction)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Button down
                    offsetX = theButton.getX() - event.getX();
                    offsetY = theButton.getY() - event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Button moved
                    float newX = event.getX() + offsetX;
                    float newY = event.getY() + offsetY;
                    v.setX(newX);
                    v.setY(newY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Button up
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    theButton.setOnTouchListener(touchBListener);
```

When I drag the button, it moves in the general direction of the drag, but it keeps jumping back and forth between its "current" spot and a spot earlier in the drag.  The jumps are larger when the drag goes in the upward right direction, for some reason.

Is a "smooth" drag possible using OnTouchListener, or do I need to use an OnDragListener instead?

Comment: Try putting a print statement (log cat out that is) on ACTION_MOVE that prints newX and newY for a sample drag. That might be more helpful for determining exactly whats going on. GO in a constant direction at steady speed

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in another post - when I change `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()`, the drags are smooth.